# Why can't this be optimized?

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, methods

I have a function that I use to add vectors, like this:

```
public static Vector AddVector(Vector v1, Vector v2)
{
    return new Vector(
      v1.X + v2.X,
      v1.Y + v2.Y,
      v1.Z + v2.Z);
}
```

Not very interesting. However, I overload the '+' operator for vectors and in the overload I call the AddVector function to avoid code duplication. I was curious whether this would result in two method calls or if it would be optimized at compile or JIT time. I found out that it did result in two method calls because I managed to gain 10% in **total** performance by duplicating the code of the AddVector as well as the dot product method in the '+' and '*' operator overload methods. Of course, this is a niche case because they get called tens of thousands of times per second, but I didn't expect this. I guess I expected the method to be inlined in the other, or something. And I suppose it's not just the overhead of the method call, but also the copying of the method arguments into the other method (they're structs).

It's no big deal, I can just duplicate the code (or perhaps just remove the AddVector method since I never call it directly) but it will nag me a lot in the future when I decide to create a method for something, like splitting up a large method into several smaller ones.

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001218.html

Comment: 99% of the time since even a 10% performance improvement is negligible in this case (inline VS 2 method calls).
What was your absolute performance gain?  I'm guessing a few MS at best.
See http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001218.html for an example.
Can't answer the question though, sorry.

Comment: OK, OK, micro-opimizations are not good--but what's the answer to the question? Can you try out different behavior with compilation flags or method attributes, etc.?

Comment: @bnkdev: I agreed with you actually. In fact our comments have a few seconds time difference and I hadn't seen yours :) I was actually discouraging micro-optimzation.

Comment: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReleaseISNOTDebug64bitOptimizationsAndCMethodInliningInReleaseBuildCallStacks.aspx

Comment: I didn't see you guys' comments either....it took me 4 minutes to try to fit all of that in a comment... :)  Didn't want to reply with an answer since I don't know the answer.

Comment: Is this a release or debug build? Also, have you tried running it through ngen? There's a limit to what the JIT compiler is able to do (since it must be fast, as it runs at loadtime), so if you want max performance, ngen might be your best bet.

Comment: Yes this is micro-optimization. However, I think knowing how something behaves in the language is important knowledge and this behaved very differently from what I expected (I expected the same performance or negligible difference).

Comment: Quite frankly, this anti-"micro optimization" fad is taking on religious forms. This is a ray tracer and as long as it's not running at 60 FPS, nothing is unnecessary optimization. I could get more performance with better algorithms (I don't even have multithreading), doesn't mean this doesn't help.

Comment: I ran the test; there is about a 20x difference between inlined unmanaged and virtual (managed) function calls. For a core math primitive in a realtime raytracer, that's huge!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't assume that `struct` is the right choice for performance.  The copying cost can be significant in some scenarios.  Until you measure you don't know.  Furthermore, `struct`s have [spooky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370859/why-isnan-is-a-static-method-on-the-double-class-instead-of-an-instance-property/370996#370996) behaviors, especially if they're mutable, but even if they're not.

In addition, what others have said is correct:

- Running under a debugger will disable JIT optimizations, making your performance measurements invalid.
- Compiling in Debug mode also makes performance measurements invalid.

Comment: Definitely true. Changing a custom vector type to a class in a ray tracer from codeproject.com (can't find the url) resulted in a significant performance boost.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful insights :)

I just changed my structs to classes, and behold, significant performance gains! I really didn't expect that either, but I'll create a new question for the questions I have with that.

Comment: That's strange, I got 10x better performance when I switched to structs from classes.

Answer (score 5):

If you compile into debug mode or begin the process with a debugger attatched (though you can add one later) then a large class of JIT optimisations, including inlining, won't happen.

Try re-running your tests by compiling it in Release mode and then running it without a debugger attatched (Ctrl+F5 in VS) and see if you see the optimisations you expected.

Answer (score 3):

> "And I suppose it's not just the overhead of the method call, but also the copying of the method arguments into the other method (they're structs)."

Why don't you test this out? Write a version of AddVector that takes a reference to two vector structs, instead of the structs themselves.

Comment: That would be slower than passing by value (depending on the struct size, but I am talking about the recommended size).

Answer (score 1):

I had VS in Release mode and I ran without debugging so that can't be to blame. Running the .exe in the Release folder yields the same result. I have .NET 3.5 SP1 installed.

And whether or not I use structs depends on how many I create of something and how large it is when copying versus referencing.

Answer (score 0):

You say `Vector` is a struct. According to [a blog post from 2004](http://blogs.msdn.com/davidnotario/archive/2004/11/01/250398.aspx), value types are a reason for not inlining a method. I don't know whether the rules have changed about that in the meantime.

Comment: Value types can be inlined on x86 from .NET 3.5 SP1 (see: http://blogs.msdn.com/vancem/archive/2008/05/12/what-s-coming-in-net-runtime-performance-in-version-v3-5-sp1.aspx); x64 supported inlining in an earlier version than this but I'm not sure which one exactly...

Answer (score 0):

Theres only one optimization I can think of, maybe you want to have a vOut parameter, so you avoid the call to new() and hence reduce garbage collection - Of course, this depends entirely on what you are doing with the returned vector and if you need to persist it or not, and if you're running into garbage collection problems.

Comment: Since it is a struct, GC isn't an issue. The only thing that changes is some minor stack usage points - but since it is the return value even this is negligible.